# Spring Data JPA: update a list of Entity using a list of input in a custom Query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following basic objects :

```
/* User class */

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;
  private String surname;

  @ManyToOne
  private Address address;
}

/* UserComposite class, used to load partial data from a user */

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserComposite {

  private Long userId;
  private String name;
  private String surname;
}
```

My goal here, is to update a list of User using a list of UserComposite as input. Here is what my DAO looks like :

```
/* UserDao class */    

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Transactional
  @Modifying
  @Query("update User u set u.name = uc.name , "
      + "u.surname = uc.surname "
      + "where u.id = uc.userId "
      + "and UserComposite uc in (?1)")
  void updateUserFromCompositeList(List<UserComposite> userCompositeList);
}
```

However, this does not work. I have a hard time matching the data from the input with the data saved in my database, especially as UserComposite is not an entity.

Is there a way around this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update multiple rows with different `ID`s values is not possible in one query.

Update every user by id

```
for (UserComposite user : List<UserComposite> userCompositeList) {
   userDao.updateUser(user.getUserId(), user.getName(), user.getSurname());
}
```

Repository query like

```java
  @Modifying
  @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.name = :name, u.surname = :surname  WHERE u.id = :userId")
  void updateUser(@Param("userId") int userId, @Param("name") String name, @Param("surname") String surname);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! does Hibernate know to do the iteration useful like a batch?

Comment: @AsfK Hibernate doesn't do a batch update for this and there is no batch update query.

Comment: Thank you, I really look for update in batch, now I can stop :) I'll check if worth to do delete and insert in the batch instead of update (~1M. records)